# How to access Docker container's data when they are not mapped to a volume?

Tags: docker

How to access Docker container's data (**not mapped to any volume**), when the container failed to start?

Let us say I started the container like this:

```
docker run -it --name testContainer ubuntu /entrypoint.sh
```

and the `entrypoint.sh` for some reason later fails to stay running (in other word the container practically doesn't start), but I want to get access to some date stored in that container (eg. /var/www/html/XYZ), How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `docker cp` on a stopped container:

```
docker cp containername:/root .
```

this will copy all the contents (recursive) from the folder /root within the container to your current dir $PWD on the host into ./root

If you need shell access, on way could be https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

Another way would be to commit the stopped container into a temporary image and then run a container from this image with an available shell:

`docker commit containername tmpimage`

`docker run -it tmpimage /bin/bash`

If the image has an ENTRYPOINT defined, you have to replace it:

`docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash tmpimage`

Change bash to ash or sh if alpine or other distro not having bash.

Comment: OK I didn't know that `docker cp` works recusively, that solves then the problem. commiting was in my mind, I just was looking for a quicker way (like cp method). Thank you. Shell access way will not work, cuz any way the container is not starting.

Comment: shell access will work with nsenter if you dont want to commit and run the new image as a container overwriting the entrypoint